# command line build for dtproj with targetsqlserverversion

Tags: build, command

Below are the two commands we have configured

1. For SQL server 2014 : 
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"  “ \DataLoad.dtproj“  /Rebuild Config2014
2. For SQL server 2016:
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"  “\DataLoad.dtproj“  /Rebuild Config2016

So before configuring these command in to TFS build we ran these commands using command prompt. 
When we run this command from command line first command with Config2014 runs successfully.
but for the Config2016 , we get a prompt asking confirmation to proceed further , and after clicking ‘Yes’, this will run successfully and create the ispac file.

[image]

Issue :

With the TFS build we need to provide this confirmation using some silent option/switch but so far we did not find any solution to configure this prompt from the command line argument for devenv.exe.
We are looking into using msbuild options rather than devenv but still we don’t get the option for msbuild either to suppress this prompt.

Comment: If option is not there, question is a dead end.